# Using plumbing roof vent as drain?

Tags: roof, vent

I'm current planning a rooftop terrace which should include a small outdoor kitchen.

I would like to know if it's possible to use the existing plumbing roof vent to connect the kitchen drain? Should I rather use the roof drain pipe ?

Thanks for your help.
Crak

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you will not want to have your entertainment and eating space right next to the roof vent anyway. Noxious sewer gas will be coming up from there that may smell to high heaven at times.

I cannot say if using the vent for a drain is acceptable to building codes. You will run some risk of water backing up into nearby sinks below if you start draining a slug of water down the vent standpipe.

Comment: Thanks, that what I though at the first place, about using the rain drain ?